# How to Prevent CSRF?

Tags: php, cakephp

How to prevent a `Cross Site Request Forgery (CSRF)` Attack in a `cakephp` web application by including a random token with each request or using a random name for each form field. A `Cross Site Request Forgery (CSRF)` Attack exploits a web application vulnerability wherein the victim unintentionally runs a script in their browser that takes advantage of their logged in session to a particular site. `CSRF` attacks can be performed over `GET` or `POST` requests.

Comment: Use the [Cross Site Request Forgery (CSRF) Middleware](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/middleware.html#csrf-middleware) ?

Comment: I think this is more a question for [your favorite search engine] than for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

If your cakephp's version is 3.0.0 < 3.5 :

There is a CSRF component is available for the same purpose in Cakephp.

Simply by adding the CsrfComponent to your components array, you can benefit from the CSRF protection it provides:

```
public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();
    $this->loadComponent('Csrf');
}
```

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/csrf.html

Newer than 3.5 should use [CsrfMiddleware](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/middleware.html#csrf-middleware) instead.